# rails 4 with CKeditor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I cannot get the galetahub ckeditor gem to work with Rails 4 for me.  I searched for any problems online but cannot find any.  I'm following the instructions exactly.

- I include gem "ckeditor" in my Gemfile
- I include gem "carrierwave" and gem "mini_magick"
- I run `rails generate ckeditor:install --orm=active_record --backend=carrierwave`
- I run `rake db:migrate`
- Inside application.rb I include `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/ckeditor)`
- Inside routes.rb I have `mount Ckeditor::Engine => '/ckeditor'`
- I'm using SimpleForm so I paste the following ERB `<%= f.input :description, as: :ckeditor %>` in my view.

And I think that's it.  But my text area does not convert to a CKeditor area for some reason.

Comment: Is your field of the `text` or `string` type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have the same problem using rails 4 and apparently the problem is that the form helper

```
form.cktext_area
```

Or in your case

```
f.input :description, as: :ckeditor
```

it's not generating what it supposed to generate, and you don't have to load the editor manually, the only thing you need to do is to is to add the class 'ckeditor' to your textarea and it will load automatically, like this:

```
f.cktext_area :body, :class => 'ckeditor'
```

Answer (score 24):

**STEP 1:** Add `gem 'paperclip'` and `gem "ckeditor"` in your gemfile.

**STEP 2:** Bundle Install.

**STEP 3:** `rails generate ckeditor:install --orm=active_record --backend=paperclip`

**STEP 4:** Place `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/ckeditor) in application.rb`

**STEP 5:** Place `mount Ckeditor::Engine => "/ckeditor"` if not present in **routes.rb** already and run `db:migrate`

**STEP 6:** Open `application.html.erb` and place this `<%= javascript_include_tag 'ckeditor/ckeditor.js' %>` in header.

**STEP 7:** Place this in footer(above the body tag) in `application.html.erb`

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('textarea').length > 0) {
        var data = $('textarea');
        $.each(data, function(i) {
            CKEDITOR.replace(data[i].id);
        });
    }
});</script>
```

**STEP 8:** Restart the WEBrick SERVER.

### That's it.

**Else**

Download the [CKEditor Zip file](http://ckeditor.com/download), extract the files and place them in the sub directory “javascripts/ckeditor”, add the main JS file to the layout..

```
javascript_include_tag 'ckeditor/ckeditor.js'
```

Place this in footer(above the body tag) in `application.html.erb`

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('textarea').length > 0) {
        var data = $('textarea');
        $.each(data, function(i) {
            CKEDITOR.replace(data[i].id);
        });
    }
});</script>
```

Comment: I followed your directions and still my textarea field does not contain any CKEditor icons.  When I run this with Rails 3.2 everything works great.

Comment: Try the new Updated alternative :)

Comment: had to replace `<%= f.input :description, as: :ckeditor %>` with `<%= f.text_area :description, :class => 'ckeditor'  %>`

Comment: it worked for me on Rails. I just had to skip Step 7. cheers!

Comment: Personally this worked, but also had to add: `CKEDITOR.basePath = '/assets/ckeditor/';` otherwise got some 404 errors in console.

Comment: The textarea I used it on just turned invisable... any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile the Galetahub gem has been updated, but it has to be updated in your app manually. Read the github page: https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor.

Answer (score 1):

ajkumar basically answered the question well already, but if you are still lost, all you need to do is download the js file, include it in your html, have a script snippet included in the HTML to activate ckeditor on a certain textarea tag ID, and then change the class of the "textarea" tag you want to change to ckeditor. Quick sample below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>A Simple Page with CKEditor</title>
        <!-- Make sure the path to CKEditor is correct. -->
        <script src="../ckeditor.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
                This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
            </textarea>
            <script>
                // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
                // instance, using default configuration.
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
            </script>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The galetahub gem is currently broken on Rails 4. This one is working fine though: https://github.com/tsechingho/ckeditor-rails

Answer (score 0):

In case you are having trouble making it work with active admin, make sure to put this:

```
config.register_javascript 'ckeditor/ckeditor.js'
config.register_javascript 'ckeditor/init.js'
```

Into `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`