# Uncaught ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor

New to Rails, and getting slow loading of assets because I'm getting a ton of errors. I'm using the AdminLTE bootstrap theme, and have added in the CSS/JS files into my assets/javascripts and assets/stylesheets accordingly.

Unsure of how to fix this.

The errors can be seen here [image: here]

in Chrome's Dev Tools:

Comment: Have you added <%= javascript_include_tag 'ckeditor/ckeditor.js' %> into your application.html.erb

Comment: Follow the steps given by @ajkumar25 here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752766/rails-4-with-ckeditor